# How to change target emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

I have several genymotion emulators for different API levels. The problem is this:

1. I run the app on a single emulator with the option 'same device for future launches' checked.
2. I open another emulator.
3. I run the the app again.

After this, the app only runs on the first emulator and I can't figure out how do I show the dialog (select target) again to run the app on both emulators.

Comment: Click Edit config beside run app.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Click **Run** → **Edit Configurations...**

[image: Edit Configurations]

Then uncheck **Use same device for future launches**

[image: Use same device for future launches]

As mentioned by @B-GangsteR, you can also launch your app on **multiple devices at the same time**. To do this, select targets using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

[image: multiple targets]

Comment: Oh. It's that simple. I tried to go there multiple times but I didn't notice that option. Thank you.

Comment: And also check answer from @b-gangster below , you might need to kill the app on target device before relaunching again

Comment: This seems to often be bypassed when instant run is enabled, especially after having executed against one emulator and then launched a new one.

Comment: See B-GangsteR's answer below if your checkbox is unchecked and it still doesn't pop the Deployment Target chooser.

Comment: There is no "Deployment Target Options" option for me.  It ends at the previous one.  Yes, I do have an app open that was launchable before.

Comment: I'm on Mac and don't have that option either

Answer (score 41):

Note that even if *"Use same device for future launches"* is unchecked, you can't launch app on other device while it is still running on first device. So you've got to

- terminate app on first device before running on another device,
- or kill adb process (it will restart),
- or run your app on **multiple devices** at the same time from the start (when choosing target, **select multiple targets using 'ctrl' button or 'ctrl' + A**)

Comment: Thanks a lot! LoL I did not even know that we can launch on multiple Emulators simultaneously :O

Comment: yup.  this is unexpected.  _lemme just ignore those settings for you_.

Answer (score 22):

In Android Studio 3.5 or above, the "Deployment Target" part of the configurations dialog has moved into the main toolbar.

[image: Main toolbar screenshot]

Comment: If you don't see toolbar - go to menu: View / Toolbar - when shown, menu option is checked.

Comment: @exscape How did you get the controls in the Toolbar to display (the things circled in red after the 'app' dropdown)? Since I updated the OS on my laptop, I can only see the first dropdown. I'm also on Android Studio 3.5.1.

Answer (score 13):

Click Edit config beside run app.

[image: On]

Comment: How did you get the shortcuts to display in the toolbar? All I have is the stuff to the left; the 'Run', icon, 'Debug', etc. don't appear. Right-click, etc. on the toolbar doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Close the existing running app in all emulators to have this option even if the problem persist after doing configuration changes

Comment: It was valid for me because when i tried to uncheck the "Use same device for future launches" check, it was already unchecked dispate Android Studio didn´t ask me for a device where to deploy the app. So, i closed the app in one emulator, and the next time, AS ask me for which device i wanted to deploy. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can change profiles by going to "Run" -> "Run..." -> "1.app" (click on the arrow) -> "Profile", then choosing which device (virtual or physical) you'd like to run on. This took me a while to find and I couldn't find anything like it in the answers above, so hopefully, I help someone out.

You can hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to select multiple devices (mentioned by @B-GangsteR).

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.5, need to click on the Emulator name which is the left option of Run 'app' button.

You can select specific Emulator of your choice or multiple Emulator as well.